# MySql Dll File In Advanced Installer

Tags: java, mysql, advanced-installer

I am creating a new .exe file for my application, My front end is Java and backend is MYSQL. Now i want to install my script in Mysql during Execution. In oracle i used the "msorcl32.dll" file  but in my sql which driver file do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DLL from the following page (zip package): http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Make sure you choose the one corespondent to your architecture (x86 or x64)otherwise the connection will fail.